# HTML5 datetime attribute question

Tags: html

I was wondering what does the `datetime` attributes value mean in the code below. can someone explain it in laymans terms piece by piece.

```
<time datetime=2010-11-13T020:00Z></time>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an [ISO 8601 date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).  You specify time units in descending order of size: year, month, date, hours, minutes, seconds.  Then you can provide time zone information after that (just a plain `Z` means UTC).

Comment: so what is the hour in the value?

Comment: Looks malformed to me.  I'm not sure if they intended it to mean 00:20:00 or 02:00:00.